# PHP: key->value from two array elements

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, I have an array where each element is a key/value pair of elements, like this:

```
[myArray] => Array
        [0] => Array
                [id] => 121
                [name] => Value1
        [1] => Array
                [id] => 125
                [name] => Value2
        [2] => Array
                [id] => 129
                [name] => Value3
                ....
```

And I want to convert this to:

```
[myArray] => Array        
        [121] => Value1
        [125] => Value2
        [129] => Value3
        ....
```

so the 'id' element becomes the key, and the 'name' element becomes the value. Does PHP have something built in (or is there a clever trick) to do this? I'd like to avoid the obvious foreach() loop if there's something cleaner available...

Comment: I don't know if there is a built-in function to handle this task, but even if there is, it's definitely using some sort of loop structure to accomplish the task. A simple foreach loop should more than suffice. Is that a problem in your implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP 5.5 has an [`array_column()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) which can do this for you, if you're lucky enough to be running that already. The developer who submitted it also [has a forwards-compatible version you can download](http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/07/the-array-column-php-userland-library/) for earlier versions of PHP.

However, it's pretty easy to roll your own, or just use a `foreach` loop for the particular case you need.

Comment: Unfortunately we're running in a 5.3 environment and that's not getting changed any time soon.

Thanks though, array_column() is EXACTLY what I needed =)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `array_column` available you can do:

```
array_column($myArray, 'name', 'id')
```

I think the `foreach` is the *much* better option, though.

Comment: why the complicated combine? `array_column($myArray, 'name','id')` would suffice..

Comment: Ah. Wasn't aware of the index argument. Nice.